# Show $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x-y|$ for $f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + x - \tan^{-1}x$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Given the function $f : (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}) \to \mathbb{R}$:
$$f(x) = \frac{\pi}{2} + x - \tan^{-1}x$$

I need to check whether $|f(x) - f(y)| < |x-y|$.

Now $$|f(x)-f(y)| = |(x-y)-(\tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}y)| \\
\leq |x-y| + |\tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}y| \\
= |x-y| + |\tan^{-1}(\frac{x-y}{1+xy})|\leq|x-y|+|\frac{x-y}{1+xy}| \, .
$$
What can I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply the triangle inequality
$$
|f(x)-f(y)|  \leq |x-y| + |\tan^{-1}x - \tan^{-1}y|
$$
then  the right-hand side is already $> |x-y|$ for $x\ne y$, so that will not lead to the desired  result.

Better use the mean-value theorem: If $x \ne y$ then
$$
 f(x) - f(y) = f'(c) (x-y)
$$
for some $c$ between $x$ and $y$. Compute the derivative and show that $|f'(c)| < 1$ for all $c$ in the domain of $f$.

Comment: That was very smooth.